# Disable camera view growing animation

Tags: swift, avcapturesession

Currently, I have a vie controller which modally presents a view controller which contains a camera. However, whenever I transition, the preview layer has an animation so it circularly grows from the top left corner to fill the rest of the screen. I've tried disabling CALayer implicit animations but to no success. Here's the code when the view appears.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    previewLayer?.frame = self.view.frame
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    capturedImageView.center = self.view.center
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    if usingFrontCamera == true {
    captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1920x1080
    }
    else {
    captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1280x720
    }

    captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)


    do {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)

        if (captureSession?.canAddInput(input) != nil) {
            captureSession?.addInput(input)

            stillImageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

            captureSession?.addOutput(stillImageOutput!)
            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
            previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
            captureSession?.startRunning()


        }


    } catch {

    }
}
```

Is there anyway to remove this growing animation? Here's a gif of the problem:

[image: GIF of animation]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you change the layer frame, there is an implicit animation. You can use `CATransaction` to disable the animation.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
    previewLayer?.frame = self.view.frame
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Comment: This answer also seems valid, but the the answer above did the trick.

Comment: @RaimKhalil Well you did say “I've tried disabling CALayer implicit animations but to no success”. But that is exactly what this answer says to do. So naturally I didn’t tell you to do that because you claimed to have done it. Besides, your two stage code would still involve a jump. - Note also that your code is still wrong because viewWillAppear can be called many times so you can end up with many preview layers!

Comment: @matt, you are correct, I did request that; I'll mark your answer as the best answer. To fix the multiple preview layers, should I just move all the code from the ViewWillAppear to ViewDidLoad?

Answer (score 4):

You are doing things in two stages. In `viewWillAppear`, you add the preview layer without giving it any size at all, so it is a zero size layer at the zero origin:

```
previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
```

Then later, in `viewDidAppear`, you grow the preview layer by giving it an actual frame:

```
previewLayer?.frame = self.view.frame
```

The two stages happen in that order and we are able to see the jump caused by the change in the frame of the preview layer.

If you don't want to see a jump, don't do that. Don't add the preview layer until you can give it its *actual* frame first.